# Error when do multiple query in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I was doing some query in php file

```
    <?php 
    include_once('Query.Class.php');
    @session_start();
    $idPlayer = $_SESSION['ID_PLAYER'];
    $obj = new Query();
    $playerData = $obj->getPlayerData($idPlayer);

    ?>
<?php 
        echo "<a href=profile.php?id=".$playerData['ID_PLAYER'].">".$playerData['USERNAME']."</a>";?></h1>
<?php 
        $playerMoney = $obj->getPlayerMoney($idPlayer);
        for($i = 1; $i <= count($playerMoney); $i++){
        echo"
            <tr>
              <td width='20' align='left'>".$playerMoney[$i]['CURENCY_NAME']."</td>
              <td width='10'>:</td>
              <td width='70' align='left'>".$playerMoney[$i]['CURENCY_AMMOUNT']."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
          ?>
<?php
        $playerInventory = $obj->getPlayerInventory($idPlayer);
        for($i = 1; $i <= count($playerInventory); $i++){
        echo"
            <tr>
              <td width='20' align='left'>".$playerInventory[$i]['ITEMS_NAME']."</td>
              <td width='10'>:</td>
              <td width='70' align='left'>".$playerInventory[$i]['QUANTITY']."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
```

this is Query.php

```
<?php
include_once('Connection.Class.php');

class Query{
    private $connection;
    public function Query(){
        $this->connection = new Connection();
    }
    public function executeQuery($str){
        $this->connection->connect();
        $result = mysql_query($str);
        if(!$result){
            $this->connection->disconnect();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $this->connection->disconnect();
            return $result;
        }
    }
    public function newExecuteQuery($str){
        $this->connection->connect();
        $result = mysql_query($str);
        if($result){
            $this->connection->disconnect();
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            $this->connection->disconnect();
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function login($username,$password,$ip_adreess){
        $username = addslashes($username);
        $md5Password = md5($password);
        $str = "CALL sp_login('$username','$md5Password','$ip_adreess')";
        $result = $this->executeQuery($str);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
            $row_array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $row_array;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function getIDPlayer($username,$password){
        $username = addslashes($username);
        $md5Password = md5($password);
        $str = "CALL sp_getPlayerData('$username','$md5Password')";
        $result = $this->executeQuery($str);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
            $row_array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $row_array;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function getPlayerData($idPlayer){
        $str="SELECT * FROM player where ID_PLAYER = '$idPlayer'";
        $result = $this->executeQuery($str);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
            $row_array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $row_array;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function getPlayerMoney($idPlayer){
        $str="CALL sp_getPlayerMoney($idPlayer)";
        $i =1;
        $result_array = array();
        $result = $this->executeQuery($str);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $result_array[$i]['CURENCY_ID']=$row['CURENCY_ID'];
            $result_array[$i]['CURENCY_AMMOUNT']=$row['CURENCY_AMMOUNT'];
            $result_array[$i]['CURENCY_NAME'] = $row['CURENCY_NAME']; 
            $i++;
        }
        return $result_array;
    }
    public function getPlayerInventory($idPlayer){
        $str="CALL sp_getPlayerInventory($idPlayer)";
        $i =1;
        $result_array = array();
        $result = $this->executeQuery($str);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $result_array[$i]['ITEMS_NAME']=$row['ITEMS_NAME'];
            $result_array[$i]['ITEMS_ID']=$row['ITEMS_ID'];
            $result_array[$i]['QUANTITY'] = $row['QUANTITY']; 
            $i++;
        }
        return $result_array;
    }

}
?>
```

I got below Error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\City\index\Query.Class.php on line 88
in invectory section. but when i delete query for money, query for inventory will return true
```

any help ?

Comment: i would suggest you to chk your query. If it is correct then chk that $this->executeQuery($str) return something or not.

Answer (score 0):

your money sql query is returning FALSE, so better to do this before running `mysql_fetch_array`, so that you know you dont have any result:

```
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Like:

```
public function getPlayerMoney($idPlayer){
 $str="CALL sp_getPlayerMoney($idPlayer)";
 $i =1;
 $result_array = array();
 $result = $this->executeQuery($str);
 if($result === FALSE) {
   die(mysql_error());
   //OR return empty array
   return array(); //empty array
 }        
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ...
```

Comment: uhmm the thing is when i try by query directly on sqlyog, it's work perfectly, 
 or when i delete player section

inventory section can be seen, but when I try to query both of them there is error,

is there any limit how many mysql_query you can call in 1 page

Comment: @UmarHasan did you try checking mysql_error(); if you see any error relaed to the query. There's no such limit with mysql_query that it can be used only once per page, you can use it as many times as you need..!

Answer (score 0):

As @Sudhir says, your query returns FALSE. Most common error handling looks like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($str) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: uhmm the thing is when i try by query directly on sqlyog, it's work perfectly, 
 or when i delete player section

inventory section can be seen, but when I try to query both of them there is error,

is there any limit how many mysql_query you can call in 1 page ?

Comment: Yes - time out of http request ;). More seriously I don't know, but I'm sure it's not the problem. Have you got any sql error?